# Switching between two style objects in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to change my style for this component on click. I haven't gotten the click handler working just yet (it's actually just lifted from some other code I've found on SO, so if you have suggestions on how to implement that I'm receptive), because I'm unsure on what the best way to switch between these two styles on click is.

Currently I tried to use "class: open" within state, and render the div with style={this.state.class}. This approach isn't working because the DOM isn't even loading correctly. Is this possible (with altered syntax of course), or is another approach better?

Please don't suggest that I use CSS to do this, because I'm doing this as an exercise to familiarize myself with React, even if it's not the "best" way to do it in a broader sense.

```
class Box extends React.Component {

  constructor(...props) {
    super(...props)
    this.state = {
      hover: false,
      class: open
    }
  }

  mouseOver = () => this.setState({hover: true});
  mouseOut = () => this.setState({hover: false});
  handleClick(e){
    if (e.target.class === 'open'){
      e.target.class = 'closed';
    } else{
      e.target.class = 'open';
    }
  }

  render(){

    const open = {
      margin: 5,
      width: 30,
      height: 30,
      backgroundColor: this.state.hover?"#80ffff":"#00e6e6",
      display: "inline-block",
      textAlign: "center"
    };

    const closed = {
      margin: 5,
      width: 30,
      height: 30,
      backgroundColor: this.state.hover?"#ff4d4d":"#ff0000",
      display: "inline-block",
      textAlign: "center"
    }

    return(
      <div style={this.state.class} onMouseOver={this.mouseOver} onMouseOut={this.mouseOut} onClick={this.handleClick}></div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: have you tried declaring the constants outside functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I refactored a bit your code to show you a working approach (hover and click):

Created a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/mrlew/wt2Ld9rn/

```
class Box extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      hover: false,
      isOpened: false
    }
  }

  mouseOver = () => this.setState({hover: true});
  mouseOut = () => this.setState({hover: false});
  handleClick(e){
     this.setState({isOpened: !this.state.isOpened});
  }

  render(){

    const open = {
      margin: 5,
      width: 90,
      height: 30,
      backgroundColor: "#80ffff",
      display: "inline-block",
      textAlign: "center"
    };

    const closed = {
      margin: 5,
      width: 90,
      height: 30,
      backgroundColor: "#ff0000",
      display: "inline-block",
      textAlign: "center"
    }



    return(
      <div style={ this.state.isOpened ? open : closed } onMouseOver={this.mouseOver.bind(this)} onMouseOut={this.mouseOut.bind(this)} onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>Hover {this.state.hover ? "!" : "?" }</div>
    )
  }
}
```

Some points:

1) you must `.bind` your callback functions. From the [React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html):

> (...) In JavaScript, class methods are not bound by default. If you forget
>   to bind this.handleClick and pass it to onClick, this will be
>   undefined when the function is actually called.
>
> This is not React-specific behavior; it is a part of how functions
>   work in JavaScript. Generally, if you refer to a method without ()
>   after it, such as onClick={this.handleClick}, you should bind that
>   method.
>
> If calling bind annoys you, there are two ways you can get around
>   this. If you are using the experimental property initializer syntax,
>   you can use property initializers to correctly bind callbacks:

2) everytime you call `.setState`, React schedules a new render call. So, in general, you don't have to (should not) change the dom by yourself (like `e.target.class`).